# How can a BP goal be recommended, but not a diastolic or systolic goal?

Tags: blood-pressure, age, hypertension, guidelines

Out of curiousity, I'm researching the JNC 8 guidelines for hypertension, and when reading [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24352797) publication, I noticed it says:

> There is strong evidence to support treating hypertensive persons aged 60 years or older to a BP goal of less than 150/90 mm Hg and hypertensive persons 30 through 59 years of age to a diastolic goal of less than 90 mm Hg; however, **there is insufficient evidence in hypertensive persons younger than 60 years for a *systolic goal*, or in those younger than 30 years for a *diastolic goal*, so the panel recommends a BP of less than 140/90 mm Hg** for those groups based on expert opinion.

My question is: How can the JNC 8 recommend an overall BP goal (which consists of both diastolic and systolic measurements), yet, they don't suggest a goal for either diastolic, or systolic, depending on the age of the person? Why do they make this distiction?

Comment: http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1511939#t=article

Comment: @Countlblis I don't see how that answers my question.. =/

Comment: You could try to ask the corresponding author of the article you cited: Paul A. James, MD, University of Iowa, 200 Hawkins Dr, 01286-D PFP, Iowa City, IA 52242-1097 (paul-james@uiowa.edu)